# Angular async pipe with offset pagination

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable that is pulling 12 people from a directory and displaying onto a template with async pipe. The API it hits is fairly basic and just uses offset pagination direct pass into the SQL query to grab the people. What I am hoping for is we have on first load, the API returns the first 12 people, then we have a 'load more' button. Hoping this button can keep the 12 people already on the screen but load in 12 more by changing the offset so first call is offset 0, next is offset 11 etc

I was looking at things like forkJoin or shareReplay because I want this to be reactive and also want to avoid asking the API for larger and larger response objects - example on load more would not want to ask for 24 just the next 12

so right now onInit I have the first of the people being pulled in

```
public people$: Observable<Directory[]> = combineLatest([this.selectedLocation$,this.selectedDepartment$, this.selectedSearchQuery$]).pipe(
switchMap(([loc,dept,query]) =>
  this.apiEmployeeService.getDirectory({
    dept: dept?.toString(),
    location: loc === 'Both' ? '%' : loc,
    offset: this.offset,
    limit: 12,
    search: query
  }),
)
```

so what can I have the load more button call from the HTML to keep existing 12 people but then refire this observable but with an **offset of + 12**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `BehaviorSubject` as a trigger to fetch more and use the [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) operator accumulate the results from multiple fetches into a single observable:

```js
const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 12;

export class AppComponent  {

  private fetch$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);
  
  public people$: Observable<Employee[]> = combineLatest([
    this.selectedLocation$,
    this.selectedDepartment$, 
    this.selectedSearchQuery$,
  ]).pipe(
    switchMap(([loc, dept, search]) => this.fetch$.pipe(
      switchMap((_, pageIndex) => this.apiEmployeeService.getDirectory({
        dept     : dept?.toString(),
        location : loc === 'Both' ? '%' : loc,
        offset   : pageIndex * ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
        limit    : ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
        search
      })),
      scan((all, page) => all.concat(page), [])
    )),
  );

  fetchMore() {
    this.fetch$.next();
  }
}
```

The reason for the nested `switchMap` is because I'm assuming that if any of the query criteria changes (*location, dept, search*), then you want the `offset` to reset back to 0.

The second parameter of the switchMap callback receives the "emission index".  We can use that to represent the "page number".  Whenever the `combineLatest` emits a new value, a fresh subscription to `fetch$` occurs, effectively resetting the index.

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vb8rjc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) where you can see this behavior in action.

Comment: Hey thanks working on this but it seems to be working great!

question though, where is pageIndex being set at? This works but not sure why or how

Comment: the `switchMap` callback function takes two parameters.  The first is the received emission, the second it the "emission index" (*basically an integer representing the sequence number of that emission*).  So, we aren't "setting" pageIndex, we are just deriving it from the "emission index".